# Does ZFC prove the universe is linearly orderable?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

It is consistent with ZFC that the universe is well-ordered, e.g. in $V=L$ where global choice holds. I also know that it is consistent that global choice fails (although I have no immediate example from the top of my head).

However one can try and ask a slightly weaker question, much like the axiom of choice implies every set can be linearly ordered, but the reversed implication fails; is it the same with global choice? The immediate answer is yes, it is consistent that the universe can be linearly ordered but the axiom of choice fails and therefore global choice has to fail too. But just how far can this be pushed?

> Can we construct a model of ZFC in which the axiom of choice holds, but there is no linear ordering of the universe? Or does ZFC prove that the universe is linearly ordered?

One would expect that it would, because if we assume AC then the sets of ordinals already decide the universe in its entire form, and sets of ordinals can always be linearly ordered by: $$A\prec B\iff\min (A\triangle B)\in A.$$ (where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference.)

Comment: In Solovay's model, there is no ordinal definable non measurable set of reals. Hence there cannot be an ordinal definable linear ordering of power set of reals because one can pass, in a definable way, from such an ordering to a non measurable set as follows: Work in Cantor space. Write x~y iff they agree on all but finitely many bits. Restrict your ordering to the ~ equivalence classes. Let X be the set of those reals x such that the eq class containing x precedes the one containing x' where x' is obtained by changing all bits of x. Then X is not Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Ashutosh, while you are correct, you should also note that I asked about ZFC, not about ZF.

Comment: I should also point out that there are simpler ways to prove there is no definable linear ordering of the universe without the axiom of choice. Simply add a non-linearly ordered set (e.g. amorphous sets).

Comment: By Solovay's model I meant the model obtained by Levy collapsing an inaccessible - AC holds here; the choice free model is obtained by passing to HOD(R).

Comment: Oh. I see. You're pointing out that ZFC cannot prove that there is an ordinal definable linear ordering. How does that help to answer the question, though? After all, ZFC does not prove V=OD.

Comment: See related question on whether there can be a global linear order without a global well-order: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111370/can-there-be-a-global-linear-ordering-of-the-universe-without-a-global-well-order

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Update.* I've repaired the argument. The idea was to
use the analogue of the usual non-AC arguments, but using a class forcing instead of just Cohen reals.

**Theorem.** Every model of ZFC has a class forcing extension
that is a model of ZFC, in which there is no class global linear
ordering of the universe that is definable from parameters.

Proof. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the Easton support class forcing
product $\mathbb{P}=\Pi_{\gamma\text{
reg}}\text{Add}(\gamma,\gamma\cdot 2)$, which forces to add
$\gamma\cdot 2$ many Cohen subsets to every uncountable regular
cardinal $\gamma$ (this is of course isomorphic to adding one).
Suppose that $G\subset\mathbb{P}$ is $V$-generic, and consider the
extension $V[G]$. The standard forcing arguments show that $V[G]$
is a model of ZFC, and in particular, of the axiom of choice.

Meanwhile, I claim that there is no class global linear ordering
of $V[G]$ that is definable in the language of set theory in
$V[G]$ using parameters. Suppose that there were, and that
$\psi(x,y,z)$ is a formula forced by a condition $q\in G$ to
define a linear order when used with the parameter named by $\dot
z$. Let $\gamma$ be a regular cardinal far above the support of
$q$ and any of the conditions appearing in $\dot z$. The forcing
at stage $\gamma$ added the mutually generic sets $g_\alpha$ for
$\alpha\lt\gamma+\gamma$. Let $A$ be the set of all $g_\alpha$
from the first block, that is, for $\alpha\lt\gamma$, and let $B$
be the set of $g_\beta$ from the second block, for
$\gamma\leq\beta\lt\gamma+\gamma$. Fix the corresponding canonical
names $\dot A$ and $\dot B$, as derived from $\dot G$. Suppose
without loss of generality that $A$ precedes $B$ in the definable
linear order, so that $\phi(A,B,z)$ holds in $V[G]$. Fix a
condition $p\in G$ below $q$ such that $p\Vdash\phi(\dot A,\dot
B,\dot z)$. The condition $p$ mentions less than $\gamma$ much
information about the stage $\gamma$ forcing. Thus, it details
fewer than $\gamma$ many bits of fewer than $\gamma$ many sets
each in $A$ and $B$. Furthermore, a density argument shows that
every possible initial segment of a subset of $\gamma$ occurs for
$\gamma$ many of the Cohen sets in each block. So every set in $A$
whose digits are partially specified by $p$ can be matched by a
set in $B$ that agrees with those digits, and vice versa. Since
$p$ specifies fewer than $\gamma$ many bits, there is in $V$ an
automorphism $\pi$ of the stage $\gamma$ forcing that carries out
a permutation of the coordinates, carrying altogether all the
$\alpha$s in the first block to $\beta$s in the second block and
vice versa, in such a way that happens to have $\pi(p)$ and $p$
both in $G$. We may extend $\pi$ to an automorphism of
$\mathbb{P}$, and consider the resulting transformation of names.
Since $\pi$ swaps the two blocks altogether, we have $\dot
A^\pi_G=B$ and $\dot B^\pi_G=A$. The choice of $\gamma$ ensures
that $\dot z^\pi=\dot z$. But since $p\Vdash\phi(\dot A,\dot
B,\dot z)$ we also have $\pi(p)\Vdash\phi(\dot A^\pi,\dot
B^\pi,\dot z^\pi)$, and as $\pi(p)\in G$, this means that
$\phi(B,A,z)$ in $V[G]$, which means that $B$ precedes $A$ in the
linear order, a contradiction. QED

This argument can be used to show, as Ali mentions in his answer, that there can be a definable class of pairs, having no choice function. Specifically, consider all sets of pairs, which would include the pairs of the form $\{A,B\}$ as I denote them in the proof. If we could definably select one or the other, then we fix a condition $p$ forcing which one is selected, and then find an automorphism $\pi$ that swaps the two elements of the pair, while having $\pi(p)$ still in $G$. Thus, the other set must also be selected, a contradiction.

**Corollary.** Every model of set theory has a class forcing extension with a definable class of unordered pairs, such that no definable class (with parameters) selects exactly one set from each of those pairs.

Comment: So if we allow $G$ as a predicate, we should be able to define a linear ordering of he universe in ZFC? Or would we still have to talk about it in NBG?

Comment: Yes. If the ground model has a global well-order, then allowing $G$ as a predicate in $V[G]$ will allow us to define a well-order in $V[G]$:  $x$ is before $y$ if $x$ has an earlier name than $y$. (For this, you have to define $V$ in $V[G]$, but this is possible by my theorem on the definability of the ground model after closure point class forcing.) 

Comment: Yes, well-ordering I understand that is definable. I imagine this is about the same proof as the usual proof that AC holds in the ground model then it holds in the extension, but for GC. Your suggestion for a next question is good; I actually had in mind something else: can we prove this definable linear order is an extension of $(V,\in)$ or $(V,\subseteq)$? Essentially this is the same track as the usual independence of linear order theorems, but with the axiom of choice holding and global choice failing...

Comment: Joel, I believe you have a couple of typos there. I will correct them now, but feel free to undo my doing if I'm just misunderstanding.

Comment: I am having a little difficulty with the above, and it will take me two or three comment blocks to explain.  The source of the difficulty is the notion of rank functions definable in strong enough fragments of ZFC.  I thought that the machinery to rank members of L not only implied a well order on L, but that such a rank extended to V, and I (possibly mis-) remember the ranking notion as absolute. (Despite Solovay's best efforts, I am still pretty weak on set theory.)  Gerhard "Continued In The Next Block" Paseman, 2012.10.27

Comment: Granted I am thinking of Conway's Surreal Numbers as I write this, and that might lead my intuition astray.  So my first naive question is, is there a simpler argument why rank functions or predicates don't provide such an order?  Also, one problem I have with proof by contradiction is that it is easy for me to insert another wrong assumption and hard to find out when I did.
Just to make this quick, e.g. why should I believe that your claimed specific automorphism pi exists? I'm hoping for an answer easier than 'Take Math 235 again.'  Gerhard "Maybe If It's On Coursera..." Paseman, 2012.10.27

Comment: Gerhard, the well-ordering of $L$ is not only generated by the rank, but by the fact that we can identify each member not only its rank but also the defining formula and its parameters. By the combination of these two we can generate a well-ordering of the universe. Outside of $L$, in strange and complicated universes obtained by class forcing (for example) one cannot do that anymore. Now not everything is definable from ordinals in the sense that $V=HOD$ (which is true in $L$, obviously), and so we might not have an effective way of deciding who's on first.

Comment: To your quick question about $\pi$, we know it exists because we can describe it. We know how the forcing looks like, and we know how to write the definition of $\pi$. Ask yourself for functions from the natural numbers into $\lbrace0,1\rbrace$, can you actually write down the automorphism which switches the values at $42$, whereas the values of all functions before $42$ remain constant? Of course you can. The idea is similar here, only applied to a much larger scale.

Comment: I may be able to write down the function which has the desired value for f(42), but then I have to convince myself that f is an automorphism.  However, I will buy that P is such that there are a sufficiency of initial fragments such that there are a wealth of automorphisms that fix each fragment and mix the rest of P in nice fashions.  Part of what I was hoping for were some order-theoretic characteristics of P.  I also hope that Joel has a different take on my difficulty so as to provide a different comment.  Gerhard "Will Think On Yours, Thanks" Paseman, 2012.10.27

Comment: Gerhard, perhaps you are thinking of the result that any partial order extends to a linear order. The issue is that although one can prove this for set orders in ZFC, using the axiom of choice, in order to extend the argument to proper class sized orders, we need a choice principle suitable for class sized objects, which is the global choice principle. In the model of my answer, although we have the axiom of choice for sets, we do not have the global choice principle, and there is no way to assemble all the set linear orders together into one class linear order. 

Comment: I'm mildly surprised that my intuition was correct, although I am not surprised that it was for the wrong reason.  I was not consciously thinking of extending set partial orders to set linear orders.  Gerhard "Not Doing Much Introspection These Days" Paseman, 2012.11.02

Comment: I've now fixed the argument, by moving up a level, which is what we should have expected by analogy with the Cohen real case. 

Answer (score 8):

> Joel nicely answers Asaf's question.
>   Here I just want to add some footnotes
>   to his answer.

**1.** Joel' argument shows that $ZFC$ cannot even prove the **definable class form of axiom of choice for pairs**. Historically, this was first done by with a similar argument by Easton in his 1964-thesis (printed in the Annals of Mathematical Logic).

**2.** In the pre-forcing era, Mostowski had already shown that $ZFA$ + "the universe can be linearly ordered" does not imply "every set can be well-ordered" (see p.51 of Jech's book on the Axiom of Choice).

**3.** As shown in the proof of Theorem 5.21 (p.71) of Jech's text, Mostwoski's argument can be transplanted to the forcing context to show that indeed $V$ can be definably linearly ordered in Cohen's so-called basic model of the failure of the axiom of choice.

Comment: Yes, to the second and third points I referred in my answer. One can observe that in the Halpern-Levy model (which is a direct and vastly more difficult Mostowski linearly ordered model) we have that the universe is linearly ordered, but the axiom of choice fails.