# When does an infinite model have a proper class-sized elementary extension?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Suppose that a set of sentences of a 1st order language has an infinite model $M$.

Under what conditions is there is a proper class-sized elementary extension of $M$?

How does the answer change if we begin with a *proper class* of sentences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your main question is that in ZFC there is always such a proper-class elementary-extension.

**Theorem.** In ZFC, every set-sized model in a set-sized
first-order language has a proper-class elementary extension.

**Proof.** This is easiest to see in the case that the global
axiom of choice holds, in other words if there is a class
well-ordering of the universe. So let me first explain that case.
Fix the global well-order and consider any fixed model $M_0$ in a
set-sized first-order language. Using the upward
Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, there is a proper elementary
end-extension of $M_0$, and we may let $M_1$ be the least such
model arising in the well-order. Continuing transfinitely, picking the least elementary-extension at each stage and unions at limit stages, we may
build up an elementary chain $$M_0\prec M_1\prec\cdots\prec
M_\alpha\prec\cdots$$ by a definable procedure whose union will be a proper-class
elementary extension of each of them and in particular of $M_0$,
as desired.

But my next observation is that in ZFC you don't actually need
global choice. If we fix $M_0$, then by the axiom of choice, we
may code $M_0$ by a set of ordinals $A$. Consider the inner model
$L[A]$, which satisfies ZFC and global choice. Since $A$ codes
$M_0$, we may undertake the argument of the previous paragraph
inside $L[A]$ to get a proper-class elementary extension of $M_0$.
In the original universe $V$, then, we get an $A$-definable proper
class elementary-extension of $M_0$, as desired. **QED**

Your second question, however, can fail in some models. I claim that it is possible to have a
definable proper-class-sized theory $T$ in a model of ZFC, such
that every subset of $T$ has a model, and so in particular the
theory is consistent, but there is no definable (allowing
parameters) model of all of $T$. For example, assume we are
working in a model of ZFC in which there is no definable linear
order. (I explained how to construct such a model in my answer to
Asaf Karagila's question,
[Does ZFC prove the universe is linearly orderable?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/110823/1946).) Let $T$ be the
theory of a linear order $<$, with a constant symbol $\hat a$ for
every object $a$. Every restriction of $T$ to only set-many
constants will have a model, since in ZFC every set is linearly
orderable, but in this model there is no definable model of all of
$T$, since there is no definable linear ordering of the universe.

Comment: Hrm... cough cough... any consistent theory with infinite models. :-)

Comment: If global choice fails completely (namely, there is no parameter from which can define a global choice function), can't you just look at the language with constants $\check a$ for every set $a$ and a function symbol $F$ such that $F(\check a)\in\check a$ for all $a\neq\varnothing$? This will be set-consistent, but not class consistent.

Comment: Asaf, that doesn't work, since in first-order logic, you can't guarantee that $F(\check a)$ is $\check b$ for some $b$. I could make a model by inventing a new object $c$ that is not a $\check b$ and setting $F(\check a)=c$ for every $a$. But your idea would work in $L_{\infty,\infty}$ logic.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right.

Comment: I realized that one may get rid of the global AC assumption by coding the model and working in L[A]. So the answer in ZFC is just plain yes, as far as getting an elementary extension of a fixed model.